# C# wrapper class and dllimport from c++

Tags: c#, c++, translation, wrapper, dllimport

The idea is to make C# wrapper class. I know the structure but I don't know how to use pointers same way or that way it works similarly since my skills in C# doesn't occur. (read translation to C# from C++). If I'm right the memory usage in C# is way different.

The structure is this.

```
public class Unknown
{
    [DllImport("UnknownSDK.dll")]
    //functions to be translated
}
```

Functions to be translated:

```
bool setA(int id, int i);
bool set1(int max, level *many);
bool getA(frame * const * const fame);
void give(frame * const * const fame);
```

Thanks in advance.

Here is the structure of level:

```
  typedef struct level {

    int A;
    int B;
    int fade;
} level;
```

Structure of frame:

```
  typedef struct frame {

    DWORD header;
    DWORD padding;
    BYTE bpadding[2];
    int asd;
    group_t group[1];
} frame;
```

I hope this clarifies it a bit. And the main problem I would say is these pointers and * const * const structure in C#. I will also tell you later what my studies taught me but it is still learning so I don't have any test code to show you since I haven't got the whole picture of it yet.

Comment: Well basicly I haven't tried anything yet since I ran to the problem I can't translate those functions even in my mind to C#. I have huge C++ project which I want to put in .NET environment and as far as I see it is the easiest way to use wrapper class and continue from that.

Comment: @mattimarvi What information on P/Invoke have you read that we can help clarify? You'll get more and better answers if you show what efforts you've taken to solve the problem yourself -- preferably by providing code you've tried that doesn't work.

Comment: Another way of doing this would be to write a C++/CLI wrapper. You would need to learn the C++/CLI syntax, but then you would not need to worry about `DllImport`, etc.

Comment: This is going to be tricky because `frame` is of variable length using the C struct hack and so p/invoke cannot marshal it.

Answer (score -1):

this is the way to import method :

```
[DllImport("UnKnowSDK.dll")]
private static extern bool setA(int id, int i);
```

And you can call simply the method like this:

```
bool res = setA(1,2);
```

To pass as a parameter a structure is necessary to know its exact structure and replicate it in c #. To manipolate the data you can use:

```
    Frame fr = new FrameStruct();
fr= (ExchangeStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(frame, typeof(FrameStruct));
```